# Firebase auth with email and password NPE

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In 10% of the cases there is a null pointer exception when trying to log in with the email and password authentication with Firebase. This only happens in the release apk. It doesn't occur in the debug app. It says it can't pass null for email. But the email is filled in. And otherwise Firebase sents an error code, but not a npe. 
This is the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'email' in authWithPassword()

at com.firebase.client.Firebase.authWithPassword(Unknown Source)

at com.example.verdienapp.ui.start.StartActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)

at com.example.verdienapp.ui.start.StartActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
```

My apologies. I should have directly added my code.
First validating the input:

```
private void validate() {
    this.mEmailEditText.setError(null);
    this.mPasswordEditText.setError(null);
    String email = this.mEmailEditText.getText().toString();
    String password = this.mPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        this.mPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = this.mPasswordEditText;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (password.length() < 6) {
        this.mPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = this.mPasswordEditText;
        cancel = true;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        this.mEmailEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = this.mEmailEditText;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!email.contains("@")) {
        this.mEmailEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = this.mEmailEditText;
        cancel = true;
    }
    if (cancel) {
        if (focusView != null) {
            focusView.requestFocus();
        }
    } else {
        Utils.closeKeyboard(getActivity(), this.mEmailEditText);
        LoginEvent event = new LoginEvent(R.id.button_login, email, password);
        BusProvider.getInstance().post(event);


    }
}
```

Then the login event:

```
private void login(final ButtonEvent buttonEvent) {
    LoginEvent loginEvent = (LoginEvent) buttonEvent;
    new LoginTask().execute();
    email = loginEvent.getEmail();
    password = loginEvent.getPassword();

}
```

And finally the login process with Firebase in a AsyncTask.

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(StartActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(“please wait..");
        progressDialog.setMessage(“authorizing...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mFirebase.authWithPassword(email, password, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                // System.out.println("User ID: " + authData.getUid() + ", Provider: " + authData.getProvider());


                Intent intent2 = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                finish();


            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                // error encountered
                switch (firebaseError.getCode()) {
                    case FirebaseError.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
                        // handle a non existing user
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_user_not_exist)
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case FirebaseError.INVALID_PASSWORD:
                        // handle an invalid password
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_invalid_password)
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        // handle other errors
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_reset_password),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }


            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that raises this exception, it will be impossible to say much. But in general the error is self-explanatory: you are passing `null` as the value of the email address. If you are absolutely certain that you are not doing that, see if you can reproduce the problem in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah, this is extremely unlikely and nobody else has reported anything similar. Start with an mcve.